# including a relation into ActiveAdmin index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a products model that I am using for ActiveAdmin. I want the category of the product is related to be listed in the table on the products index page. Everything I have tried from googling either errors or just shows the name of the product instead of the name of the category.

products.rb

```
belongs_to :category
```

categories.rb

```
has_many :products
```

admin/products.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  index do
    column :id
    column :name
    column :description
    column :image_name
    column :style
    column :brand
    column "Category" do |item|
      item.name
    end
    column :price
    column :product_url
    default_actions
  end
end
```

Just prints the products name instead of the categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed it

```
column "Category" do |cat|
  cat.items_category.name
end
```

Comment: If you do `column :category` (to use the model of the initial post), it will automatically use its `name` method (if it has one) and create a link. However -- and that's my problem -- it's not sortable.